# How to define a sort of reference in METAPOST?

Tags: metapost, metafont

Assume we are defining a `canvas` abstract data type in METAPOST, where some tasks are gathered. I would like to define a kind of *reference* to the last added task, but I do not know METAPOST good enough to figure out which macro concept I should use.

Here is a no-op code illustrating the use of such a reference:

```
def task text TASK =
  vardef TASK.init =
  enddef;
enddef;

def canvas text CANVAS =
  numeric CANVAS._task_n;
  task CANVAS._task[];

  vardef CANVAS.init =
    #@._task_n := 0;
  enddef;

  vardef CANVAS.current_task =
    #@._task[#@._task_n]
  enddef;

  vardef CANVAS.add_task =
    #@._task_n := #@._task_n + 1;
    % #@.current_task.init; % ! Yield an isolated expression `init`
    #@._task[#@._task_n].init;
  enddef;

enddef;

canvas c;
c.init;
c.add_task;
bye;
```

How can I correctly define the `current_task` macro, so that I can modify the `add_task` macro to refer to the `current_task` instead of `#@._task[#@._task_n]` (as suggested in the comment)?

Comment: I'm an regular user of MetaPost, but can't understand the question. Maybe you should ask the MetaPost mailing list: http://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/metapost The MetaPost developers and top-specialists will probably be able to answer.

Comment: I would like to refer to `#@._task[#@._task_n]` in a symbolic way, i.e. to be able to write something like `#@.current_task.init` instead of `#@._task[#@._task_n].init` but my current approach does not work.  Thank you to point out the mailing list.